# Windows Service is not Working

Tags: c#, .net

I had made a windows service in visual studio 2008 in C#. inside the service i had written only single line  code

```
 try
 {
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"E:\Users\Sk\Desktop\category.txt");
 }
 catch { }
```

then i  add the project installer & change the serviceProcessInstaller1   Account property as local system Also change the serviceInstaller1 start type property as Automatic.
then i build the project.it was successful. after that i add another project that was setup project.i had added primary project output & i had added the custom action as "Primary output from DemoWindowsService (Active)".then built the setup.setup was build successfully.then i install the setup & then went to services start the service.service stated properly but it was not performing the task.
i had checked the path is correct & also i tried to do

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"E:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe")` but still result is same.i tried a lot but not getting the answer.

Comment: Where did you write the code you mentioned (in which method I mean)? What is your actual objective? Why do you want to just open notepad? Could you please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not working, then maybe it's because an exception was thrown. However, since you're hiding all exceptions with your try/catch block, you'll never know what's wrong.

Get rid of the try/catch block, and see if that helps you learn what's wrong.

Comment: Right, I was just about to comment about that empty catch block.

Comment: @prateeksaluja20: Also, check the `eventvwr` for whats wrong.

Comment: @KMan: except the event viewer won't show anything because of the catch block!

Comment: I meant, after `Get(ting) rid of the try/catch block`, check the event viewer.

Answer (score 6):

Windows services cannot interact with the desktop by default, and Notepad is an interactive application.

If you open *Task Manager*, I suspect you will see the `notepad.exe` process running after you started your service, and that your service is doing what you think, it's just not visible.

You can change a service to interact with the desktop by right-clicking it in the *Services* MMC snap-in (`Start -> Run -> Services.msc`), and checking the **Allow service to interact with desktop** option on the `Log On` tab.

Relying on this option is **not** recommended though, as Microsoft have said they will remove it in later versions of Windows.

It makes sense if you think about it, since a Windows service is meant to be usable even if no-one is logged on to the computer (e.g. there is no "desktop" to interact with).

Answer (score 0):

Have you written your single line of code in the OnStart() method in the service?
If you did, then change your catch block to `catch (Exception ex)` and write the exception details to the eventlog to see why the exception occurred.

See [Logging Information About Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984385(VS.71).aspx)